# Xdebug stopped working on PHP tracing on Windows 10

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xampp, xdebug

I am completely new on PHP and Xdebug. I have installed XAMPP on Windows 10 and I have a running application on PHP.

So I wanted to trace the application on Visual Studio Code to understand it, I used the Xdebug. I did the following:

1. I download the appropriate php-xdebug.dll (according to PHP version, on xdebug.org/wizard) and place it on PHP directory of XAMPP.
2. I installed the PHP debug extension and added these lines:

   ```ini
   xdebug.mode = debug
   xdebug.start_with_request = yes
   xdebug.client_port = 9000
   ```
3. Add this line to json:

   ```
   "runtimeExecutable": "C:\\Xampp\\PHP\\php.exe"
   ```
4. Restart the Apache service in XAMPP.

Now I started the application and put some breakpoint to trace the application. It worked fine for about 4 or 5 hours, without any problem. But after that it stop working.

When I put the breakpoint it enters the breakpoint. When I press "press into" button, nothing happens and it seems Xdebug not working.

How can I check what is the problem with Wdebug?

---

**EDIT:**

This is what I found. This is a very simple code which I want to trace:

```php
<?php

$a=100;
$b=200;
echo $a."<br/>";
echo $b."<br/>";

echo $a+$b;
```

If I place in the root of `htdocs`, the Xdebug won't work any more, but if I put in a subdirectory inside `htdocs` then the debug works fine.

This the result in Xdebug log file:

```
[8668] Log opened at 2262-04-09 09:08:59.927045
[8668] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000.
[8668] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: localhost:9000 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.2.34" protocol_version="1.0" appid="8668"><engine version="3.0.4"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2021 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_list -i 1
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="1"></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_list -i 2
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="2"></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_list -i 3
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="3"></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_list -i 4
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="4"></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_list -i 5
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="5"></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_list -i 6
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="6"></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 7 -t line -f file:///c:/xampp/htdocs/test/1.php -n 3
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="7" id="86680001"></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 8 -t line -f file:///c:/xampp/htdocs/1.php -n 3
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="8" id="86680002"></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 9 -t line -f file:///c:/xampp/htdocs/app/hmi/API/addline.php -n 16
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="9" id="86680003"></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 10 -t line -f file:///c:/xampp/htdocs/app/hmi/API/addorderstation.php -n 17
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="10" id="86680004"></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 11 -t line -f file:///c:/xampp/htdocs/app/hmi/API/addstation.php -n 14
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="11" id="86680005"></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 12 -t line -f file:///c:/xampp/htdocs/index.php -n 3
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="12" id="86680006"></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 13 -t line -f file:///c:/xampp/htdocs/index.php -n 17
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="13" id="86680007"></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_list -i 14
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="14"><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/app/hmi/API/addstation.php" lineno="14" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="86680005"></breakpoint><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/app/hmi/API/addorderstation.php" lineno="17" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="86680004"></breakpoint><breakpoint type="line" filena
[8668] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_list -i 15
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="15"><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/app/hmi/API/addstation.php" lineno="14" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="86680005"></breakpoint><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/app/hmi/API/addorderstation.php" lineno="17" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="86680004"></breakpoint><breakpoint type="line" filena
[8668] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 16 -t exception -x *
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="16" id="86680008"></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- run -i 17
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="17" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/index.php" lineno="3"></xdebug:message></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- stack_get -i 18
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="18"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/index.php" lineno="3"></stack></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 19 -- KCRh
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="19" status="break" reason="ok"><error code="206"><message><![CDATA[error evaluating code]]></message></error></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 20 -- Y2hyKCRhKQ==
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="20"><property type="string" size="1" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[AA==]]></property></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 21 -- JGE=
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="21"><property type="null"></property></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 22 -- JF9SRVFVRVNUWydQQVJBTVMnXQ==
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="22"><property type="null"></property></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 23 -- JHBhcmFtcw==
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="23"><property type="null"></property></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- context_names -i 24 -d 0
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_names" transaction_id="24"><context name="Locals" id="0"></context><context name="Superglobals" id="1"></context><context name="User defined constants" id="2"></context></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- context_get -i 25 -d 0 -c 0
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="25" context="0"><property name="$a" fullname="$a" type="uninitialized"></property><property name="$b" fullname="$b" type="uninitialized"></property></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- step_over -i 26
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_over" transaction_id="26" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[8668] [Step Debug] <- stop -i 27
[8668] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stop" transaction_id="27" status="stopped" reason="ok"></response>

[8668] Log closed at 2262-04-09 09:08:59.927045
```

Comment: "(enabling remote-debug and autostart remote-debug)" is a little ambiguous. Please edit the question to include the exact settings that you've made.

Comment: I don't get it now... your log shows that it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only I could do , I changed the website Folder from htdocs to htdocs/Projects. and everything worked fine after that. I couldn't find the reason

Answer (score 1):

You can check what Xdebug does, by creating a log with the php.ini setting `xdebug.log=c:\temp\xdebug.log`—you might have to change the path if the web server or PHP can't write to that. The log will list all debug connection attempts, list potential connection issues, and if a connection is made, the communication. You can check whether the `fileuri` XML attribute of the `<init` tag matches what is set by the `breakpoint_set` commands that the IDE ought to send.

Comment: I edited that I added the php.ini, they are on the above post

Comment: OK - cool, I removed that bit from the answer then.